# How to perform Animations in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, ios, windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8

Please tell me how to do animations in windows phone 8 like in iOS.

I mean similar functionality of
`[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animtaion:{} completion:{}];`

Is it possible to realize this with Storyboard and `DoubleAnimation` (or something like this) without setting target and other properties ?

Now I'm doing like this:

```
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        myDoubleAnimation.From = 10;
        myDoubleAnimation.To = 50;
        myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

        // Configure the animation to target the button's Width property.
        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation, selectedItem);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(ListBoxItem.HeightProperty));

        // Create a storyboard to contain the animation.
        Storyboard myHeightAnimatedButtonStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        myHeightAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
        myHeightAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Begin();
```

I hope You understand what I need :)
Thank You;

Comment: In XAML it would be shorter... Are you just looking for shorter/better notation?  how often do you use this, in what manner?

Answer (score 1):

Story Board runs on UI elements hence its mandatory to set a target element to see animated effects,and as per as setting other properties are concerned I would suggest the use of expression blend for the same. Its a wonderful tool.